# Using postman.setNextRequest() to populate request body before Send

Tags: javascript, postman

I have a postman collection with two requests.

- POST `/make-request`
- GET `/prepare-request`

The body of `/make-request` has a variable in it like so.

```
{
  "key": {{key}}
}
```

The `Tests` tab of the `/prepare-request` takes it's response JSON body and puts sets `data.key` as a global variable `key` in postman like this.

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("key", data.key);
```

Now when I `Send` the requests in this order

1. GET `/prepare-request`
2. POST `/make-request`

The body of `/make-request` is populated with the response from `/prepare-request`

Now...

What I would like to have is a `Pre-request Script` in `/make-request` that runs `/prepare-request` before and automatically populates the body of `/make-request` every time, before it runs. I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
postman.setNextRequest("/prepare-request")
```

Thoughts? Is this the correct usage of `.setNextRequest()`. Is there anyway I can get this functionality our of postman and [newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman).

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for `newman` you don't need to use `.setNextRequest()` as long as you order your requests in the collection so that they fetch the data and set the env variables in the right order the the request work.

1. GET `/prepare-request`
2. POST `/make-request`

Answer (score 0):

postman.setNextRequest("/prepare-request") looks like it isn't quite right. The parameter you want to supply (as I understand it) is the NAME of the call you want to make, not the url. So...that is probably more like:
postman.setNextRequest("Prepare Request"); using whatever name you gave that API in POSTMAN.